# I have to resize my JFrame for the contents to show up. How can i fix that?

Tags: java, swing, resize, jframe

When I run my gui, I have to resize the window for everything to show up. Does someone know what the problem is?

Comment: Call pack method of JFrame before making it visible..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Call pack() on your JFrame, after adding all your components and before calling setVisible(true).

Answer (score 2):

When you create the frame call the `setSize()` method on the frame to set the initial starting size.

Answer (score 2):

```
setVisible(true);
```

after you have added all desired JComponents to your JFrame helped for me.

Comment: you're right , if the `setVisible(true);` statement is placed anywhere before adding all the components to the JFrame the problem occurs and adding it after adding all the components it doesn't occur

Answer (score 0):

don't need to add pack() method.

Just add the setSize(int, int) on the end of everything, then it will work well.

and setVisible(true) on next to setSize.

Answer (score 0):

I was also having the same problem.

After making any change on the `JFrame` view, just recall the `setVisible(true)` method. It just worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

The [setBounds()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#setBounds%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) method will resize and reposition a Window. however you might want to look at the way your components are laid out if [pack()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#pack%28%29) isn't working (I believe it relies on minimum/preferred sizes of components).